# Jetpack Compose - About Preview widthDp and heightDp

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

What are `widthDp` and `heightDp` as a `@Preview` parameter?

【My environment】

- Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch3 build on October 1, 2021
- Gradle: 7.0.2
- AGP: 7.0.3
- androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.0.1

Here is my code.

```
@Preview(
    showBackground = true,
    widthDp = 200,
    heightDp = 200,
)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.Red))
}
```

And preview shows below.
[image]

But I expected below.
[image]

It seems that the box size is larger than I expected.
Does anyone explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Preview.kt` codebase,

> @param widthDp Max width in DP the annotated @[Composable] will be
> rendered in. Use this to restrict the size of the rendering
> viewport.
> @param heightDp Max height in DP the annotated
> @[Composable] will be rendered in. Use this to restrict the size of
> the rendering viewport.

The parameters are to restrict the maximum rendering viewport.
It seems they scale the composable if the given dimensions are large/smaller than the actual dimensions of the composable.

Answer (score 3):

This is somehow a bug with @Preview, the first composables take the hole space they have, can't explain why. Even without the two parameters `widthDp = 200, heightDp = 300,` The first Box takes all the space. So for now to get the result you want you have to put a box around which "protects" the main composables.